# Printer losing image details when printing

Tags: printer

When I tried printing a regular Google Map image, but it came out like this:
[image]

What setting would I have to change to make it print properly?

Comment: What make and model printer do you have?

Comment: the model is hp psc 1310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire page, both text and images, is highly faded.  This is unlikely to be caused by software, so try troubleshooting the printer itself.

If this is from an inkjet printer:

- Print the nozzle check page and determine if any print head nozzles are clogged.  If so, try cleaning the print head.
- Reseat the cartridges; shaking them a few times before installing them may help.
- Replace any low ink cartridges.
- If you are using remanufactured or third-party cartridges, try using genuine OEM cartridges.

If this is from a laser printer (note that not all parts may be replaceable on your printer):

- Replace any low toner cartridges.
- Clean any parts in the printer that require regular cleaning.
- If the drum is separate from the toner cartridge, inspect it for damage and foreign material stuck on the drum unit.  (Limit exposure of the drum to light; prolonged exposure to light or exposure to bright light will damage it.)
- Make sure the fuser is heating up while printing.
- Check if the transfer belt is damaged.

If none of these work, you probably have a broken printer, and you'll need to replace it or have it serviced.

### Edit

The HP PSC 1310 uses cartridge-integrated print heads, so try replacing the print cartridges as this will replace the heads at the same time.  This printer accepts standard-yield 27 (black) and 28 (tricolor) cartridges, or high-yield 56 (black) and 57 (tricolor) cartridges.

Answer (score 0):

Try increase the contrast setting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your printer is running out of ink. Have you checked to make sure the printer has enough ink?

Comment: it has enough ink

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [steps suggested here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00127366&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=360489&prodTypeId=18972) and see if the settings makes a difference and whether the self test works OK.

Comment: Hey lookie here—a [dead link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).